# Edit local yaml file in rust

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to edit yaml file using [serde_yaml](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml) but using this i'm only able to edit in stdout but cannot write back to local file(`/home/home/.kube/config`)

```
    let kubeconfig = "/home/home/.kube/config"
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(kubeconfig)
    .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

    let mut value: serde_yaml::Value = serde_yaml::from_str(&contents).unwrap();
    *value.get_mut("current-context").unwrap() = "new_user".into();
    // Below lines shows the edited file in stdout
    serde_yaml::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &value).unwrap();
```

I did tired as below an other method but had no luck.

```
    let writer = serde_yaml::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &value).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",writer); // shows ()
    serde_yaml::to_writer(writer);
```

How do i write this edit back to `/home/home/.kube/config` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use `to_writer` as `to_string`:

```rust
let writer = serde_yaml::to_string(&value).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", writer);
```

Then you can save the string how you usually would.

---

Or, alternatively, you could write directly to a file:

```rust
let mut file = File::create("/home/home/.kube/config").unwrap();
serde_yaml.to_writer(&mut file, &value);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now able to edit with to_string. but alternative solution is not working with serde_yaml.to_writer(&mut file, &value); shows "use the path separator to refer to an item"